# postsharp - Parameter value based caching

Tags: caching, postsharp

I am using the postsharp cache and I have created a sample function to cache the result of that - but I want to do caching based on parameter values only.

For example, my function looks like this

```
[Cache(SlidingExpiration = OneHour, IgnoreThisParameter = true )]
public IEnumerable<String> Get(int dateId)
{
  // code processing
}
```

I want the output of this function to be cached if the dateid= T-1 (yesterday) and not when dateid is not T.

But with [Cache] attribute decorated, everything gets cached. Basically I want to cache T-1 data only and not data for any other dates.

This pattern is used so that we can invalidate the caches using custom methods but I dont see any option for selective parameter value based caching.

Can anybody respond to this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible. At this moment you need to split method into three methods and have:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get(int dateId)
{
  if (dateId == CurrentDate - 1)
    GetCached(dateId);
  else
    GetCore(dateId);
}

[Cache(SlidingExpiration = OneHour, IgnoreThisParameter = true )]
private IEnumerable<string> GetCached(int dateId)
{
  return GetCore(dateId);
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetCore(int dateId)
{
  // ...
}
```

This is in the backlog, but it is not scheduled to any release at the moment.